# How to read the label name from a file

Tags: angular, service

I need to put in a file all label names and i need to take values. I don't need to translate in other languaes.

My question is how can i do this?

I need to create a service that read the json file , so the other component can read value?

Or are there some other method?

Comment: you can use browser local storage as well for storing and retrieving data.

Comment: is not the correct solution for me. Do you know other method?

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not support working with local files on the system due to securtiy reasons. Becuase it would be vulnerable if a web page access system files. 
If you are building an offline application and it is a desktop app you might try to check [electron](https://www.electronjs.org). But that's only if it is a desktop application, if it runs in the browser then it is just not possible.
Hope it will answer your question.